# PHP: File is Not Uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

I have the following code but file is not uploading in the directory:

```
<?php
    include "includes/dbconn.php";
    $tbl_name="finfo"; // Table name 
    $fname=$_POST['T1'];
    $fn=$_FILES['file']['name'];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        $source = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $target = "uploads/".$fn;
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
        echo $source. "<br>";
        echo $target. "<br>";
        echo $fn. "<br>";
    }

    $furl= "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $fsize= (round ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024)) . " kB";
    $nod=0;
    $sqlinsert="insert into " . $tbl_name ." (fname,furl,fsize,nod) values     ('".$fname."','".$furl."','".$fsize."',".$nod.")";
    $rsadd = mysql_query($sqlinsert);
    if(!$rsadd) {
        echo "Ehh, Something going wrong!!!!";
    } else {
        echo "One Record Inserted Successfully!!!";
    }
?>
```

Please dont bother with the SQL, I have no problem with that.. but the file is not uploading in the directory. The directory is in the same parent folder where this php files belongs.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions?

Comment: You should also check so the actual file is set in the `$_FILES` array: `if(isset($_FILES['file']))`

Comment: If you are submitting it with a form, check whether the form has appropriate enctype, also check the permissions on that folder whether the folder is write able as suggested by @BenFortune

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check would be that the directory is writable. In your development environment changing the folder permissions to 766 would be acceptable for testing.